# How to Write a two dimensional array in a fine rectangle in console application

Tags: c#, arrays, console

Please i have an array of size `int[][]` and i want to display it in a finely arange manner on console. Basically its a 2048 game in console. So i want to display it in a 4 row 4column manner. Unlike the usual 2048, this one displays 0 for null. So please how i achieve this ?

Previously i just indent like below

```
 public static string Indent(int count)
 {
      return "".PadLeft(count);
 }
```

and the console writ elike

```
for (int i = 0; i < Tiles.Count(); i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < Tiles[i].Count(); j++)
          {
             Console.Write(Indent(2) + Tiles[i][j]);
          }
          Console.WriteLine();
   }
```

The problem now is that. The arrangement get destroyed when the tiles reaches 2 to 3 decimal numbers. Please any alternative , guide or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to keep the layout the same no matter what numbers are in there, increase the intent count to 5. Then, whenever you get a number with four or more decimal numbers divide it by 1024 and add a "k" after it. So instead of "2048" write "2k".

The other option would be to find the highest number in the column, count it's decimal spaces and add 1 to the intent count of every value in that column.